# How to increment value of a specific cell using apply function (R)?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been trying to increment a value in R using the apply function. I am currently doing:

```
t(apply(df[rownames,], 1, fun))
```

where fun is: ( I want to check if my third column value is less than 10, if yes, increment by 1)

```
fun<- function(x) {
  if(x[3]>=10) {
    x[2:3] <-0
    
  }else {
    
   x[3] = x[3] +1 // This does not work      
  
  }
  print(x)
  
}
```

**Dataframe:**

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

**Expected Output:**

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

**Error:
Error in x[3] + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator**

Comment: The problem with your function is that you need to return something from it.  Add `return(x)` as a last line.

Comment: The logic of your problem-statement and your expected output are inconsistent: why are rows 1 and 3 values for `C3` not incremented as well?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ifelse` for this, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
read.table( text = "C1  C2  C3  C4
1   0   0   0
2   1   1   0
3   0   0   0
4   1   1   0", header = T) %>% 
  mutate(C3 = ifelse(C3 < 10 & C3 !=0, C3 +1, C3))


 C1 C2 C3 C4
1  1  0  0  0
2  2  1  2  0
3  3  0  0  0
4  4  1  2  0
```

Comment: I think you're missing that the OP function sets both the second and third columns to 0 if `>=10` (see `x[2:3] <-0`).

Answer (score 1):

Up front:

- your logic is inconsistent with your expected output; I think you may also need `&& x[3] > 0` in your incrementing step, not entirely sure; I'll ignore this for the code below;
- a function that is meant to modify data should always return the data, not (just) `print` it. In my opinion, functions should only `print(.)` when explicitly needed for debugging or verbose operations, in which case I like to add an argument to disable it, perhaps one of

  ```r
  fun <- function(x, verbose=FALSE) ...
  fun <- function(x, quiet = TRUE) ...
  ```
- much of the discussion below is based on the premise that what you need to do is more complicated than just increment/set a column or two; if that is truly all you need to do, then I strongly suggest you learn how to do things in R in a *vectorized* way, as many things are easier (to read/maintain) and much more efficient.
- while numeric indexing (`x[3]`) works, it seems a shame (and more fragile) to use that when you have names available. If you must stay with `apply`, then `x` is a named vector, so you can do `x["C3"]`, etc.

---

There's no need to use `apply`, R can do things much more quickly as vectors. Know that an R `data.frame` is mostly just a `list` where each column is its own vectors (*usually*), so if you want to do something on a specific column, work on the column by itself. In this case, we can do simply:

```r
ind <- df$C3 < 10 & df$C3 > 0
df$C3[ind] <- df$C3[ind] + 1
df$C2[!ind] <- df$C3[!ind] <- 0
df
#   C1 C2 C3 C4
# 1  1  0  0  0
# 2  2  1  2  0
# 3  3  0  0  0
# 4  4  1  2  0
```

There are further problems when using `apply(df, 1, ..)`, however: if there is one or more `character` column, then using `apply(.., MARGIN=1, ..)` will likely break what you are doing because it calls `as.matrix(df)` before doing row-wise operations. Proof:

```r
> apply(df, 1, function(z) { browser(); z; })
Called from: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
Browse[1]> debug at #1: z
Browse[2]> z
C1 C2 C3 C4 
 1  0  0  0 
Browse[2]> Q
> df$newcol <- "a"
> apply(df, 1, function(z) { browser(); z; })
Called from: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
Browse[1]> debug at #1: z
Browse[2]> z
    C1     C2     C3     C4 newcol 
   "1"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "a" 
Browse[2]> Q
```

If you *must* do things row-wise on a frame, then you can safely choose `apply` for it if (a) the columns you need are all the same class or you don't need to do number-ops on them; or (b) you subset the frame so that the columns you pass to `apply` are all the same class (non-`character`). If you cannot follow those, then you should likely shift to using `mapply` (returns simplified vector/array) or `Map` (returns a `list`). For instance, assuming that your operation here needs to be on the entire row (which I showed above that it does not), then

```r
fun <- function(...) {
  x <- list(...)
  if (x$C3 >= 10) {
    x[c("C2", "C3")] <- 0
  } else {
    x$C3 <- x$C3 + 1
  }
  x
}
```

and then you need to call it specially in order to make it column-agnostic (not pre-defined on the number of columns:

```r
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, do.call(Map, c(list(f = fun), df)))
df
#   C1 C2 C3 C4
# 1  1  0  1  0
# 2  2  1  2  0
# 3  3  0  1  0
# 4  4  1  2  0
```

This seems cumbersome, though. It might be clearer to define the function so that it only works on exactly two columns at a time, so perhaps

```r
fun2 <- function(C2, C3) {
  if (C3 >= 10) { 
    C2 <- C3 <- 0
  } else {
    C3 <- C3 + 1
  }
  list(C2, C3)
}
mapply(fun2, df$C2, df$C3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] 0    1    0    1   
# [2,] 1    2    1    2   
df[c("C2","C3")] <- asplit(mapply(fun2, df$C2, df$C3), 1)
df
#   C1 C2 C3 C4
# 1  1  0  1  0
# 2  2  1  2  0
# 3  3  0  1  0
# 4  4  1  2  0
```

This cumbersome function, though, is only required if the operations you are doing truly must not be vectorized.